# Update score on screen after watching video ad

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, nsuserdefaults

Ihave two scenes `GameScene` and `BonusScene`I use `NSUserDefaults` to save winning count, everything works fine, I add video reward ad, after watching video, you get 5 points, that works too, but score update on screen only happens when after you go to different scene and come back, but when I use `NSLog()` I see that update happens, but I dont know how to do it in real time on screen.
Here what I got:

```
    losingCount=[scoreprefs integerForKey:@"losingCount"];
    SKLabelNode *winsCoutnt = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"ROTORcap Extended Bold"];
    winsCoutnt.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)losingCount];
    winsCoutnt.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + 100,(CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)) + self.frame.size.height/4 );
    winsCoutnt.fontSize = 15.f;
    [self addChild:winsCoutnt];



 if([Chartboost hasRewardedVideo:@"NetworkVideo"] == YES) {

            NSUserDefaults *scoreprefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

            losingCount =[scoreprefs integerForKey:@"losingCount"];
            losingCount = losingCount +5;
            [scoreprefs setInteger:losingCount forKey:@"losingCount"]; }
```

So my question is **How can I update Score in scene on screen in real time, without going to different scene and coming back?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update the text where you're updating the NSUserDefaults

```
    losingCount=[scoreprefs integerForKey:@"losingCount"];
SKLabelNode *winsCoutnt = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"ROTORcap Extended Bold"];
winsCoutnt.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)losingCount];
winsCoutnt.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + 100,(CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)) + self.frame.size.height/4 );
winsCoutnt.fontSize = 15.f;
[self addChild:winsCoutnt];



if([Chartboost hasRewardedVideo:@"NetworkVideo"] == YES) {

        NSUserDefaults *scoreprefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        losingCount =[scoreprefs integerForKey:@"losingCount"];
        losingCount = losingCount +5;
        [scoreprefs setInteger:losingCount forKey:@"losingCount"]; 

        winsCoutnt.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)losingCount];
}
```